# Worksheet export to PDF

Tags: c#

I would like to export a specific worksheet of my excel file to PDF.
When I do wbk.ExportAsFixedFormat it work but it dosn't work when I do worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat.

Someone can help me?

I have to "activate" the worksheet maybe ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace XLConvert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\ALPIC\Desktop\XL\0000351608.xlsx");
            var worksheet = wkb.Sheets["FRA"];

            worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, @"C:\Users\ALPIC\Desktop\XL\0000351608.pdf");
            wkb.Close(false, @"C:\Users\ALPIC\Desktop\XL\0000351608.xlsx");
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkb);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found !

I tried this and it works :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\ALPIC\Desktop\XL\0000351608.xlsx");
            ((Worksheet)wkb.Sheets["FRA"]).ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, @"C:\Users\ALPIC\Desktop\XL\0000351608.pdf");; //activates first sheet

            wkb.Close(false, @"C:\Users\ALPIC\Desktop\XL\0000351608.xlsx");
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, `var worksheet = wkb.Sheets["FRA"];` gets assigned as a worksheet collection, while you specifically assigned wkb as a workbook, which has that function.